# Oriented Bounding Box algorithm, Need some understanding/clarification of a few lines of existing (working) code

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, computational-geometry

I am reviewing some MATLAB code that is publicly available at the following location:
https://github.com/mattools/matGeom/blob/master/matGeom/geom2d/orientedBox.m

This is an implementation of the rotating calipers algorithm on the convex hull of a set of points in order to compute an oriented bounding box. My review was to understand intuitively how the algorithm works however I seek clarification on certain lines within the file which I am confused on.

On line 44: `hull = bsxfun(@minus, hull, center);`. This appears to translate all the points within the convex hull set so the calculated centroid is at (0,0). Is there any particular reason why this is performed? My only guess would be that it allows straightforward rotational transforms later on in the code, as rotating about the real origin would cause significant problems.

On line 71 and 74: `indA2 = mod(indA, nV) + 1;` , `indB2 = mod(indB, nV) + 1;`. Is this a trick in order to prevent the access index going out of bounds? My guess is to prevent out of bounds access, it will roll the index over upon reaching the end.

On line 125: `y2  = - x * sit + y * cot;`. This is the correct transformation as the code behaves properly, but I am not sure why this is actually used and different from the other rotational transforms done later and also prior (with the calls to rotateVector). My best guess is that I am simply not visualizing what rotation needs to be done in my head correctly.

Side note: The external function calls `vectorAngle`, `rotateVector`, `createLine`, and `distancePointLine` can all be found under the same repository, in files named after the function name (as per MATLAB standard). They are relatively uninteresting and do what you would expect aside from the fact that there is normalization of vector angles going on.

Comment: Have you tried asking the author? It is very hard for people to answer questions about individual lines of code from a big function with no context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the above piece of code, so I can give some explanations about it:

First of all, the algorithm is indeed a rotating caliper algorithm. In the current implementation, only the width of the algorithm is tested (I did not check the west and est vertice). Actually, it seems the two results correspond most of the time.

Line 44 -> the goal of translating to origin was to improve numerical accuracy. When a polygon is located far away from the origin, coordinates may be large, and close together. Many computation involve products of coordinates. By translating the polygon around the origin, the coordinates are smaller, and the precision of the resulting products are expected to be improved. Well, to be honest, I did not evidenced this effect directly, this is more a careful way of coding than a fix…

Line 71-74! Yes. The idea is to find the index of the next vertex along the polygon. If the current vertex is the last vertex of the polygon, then the next vertex index should be 1. The use of modulo rescale between 0 and N-1. The two lines ensure correct iteration.

Line 125: There are several transformations involved. Using the rotateVector() function, one simply computes the minimal with for a given edge. On line 125, one rotate the points (of the convex hull) to align with the “best” direction (the one that minimizes the width). The last change of coordinates (lines 132->140) is due to the fact that the center of the oriented box is different from the centroid of the polygon. Then we add a shift, which is corrected by the rotation.

Answer (score 1):

I did not really look at the code, this is an explanation of how the rotating calipers work.

A fundamental property is that the tightest bounding box is such that one of its sides overlaps an edge of the hull. So what you do is essentially

- try every edge in turn;
- for a given edge, seen as being horizontal, south, find the farthest vertices north, west and east;
- evaluate the area or the perimeter of the rectangle that they define;
- remember the best area.

It is important to note that when you switch from an edge to the next, the N/W/E vertices can only move forward, and are readily found by finding the next decrease of the relevant coordinate. This is how the total processing time is linear in the number of edges (the search for the initial N/E/W vertices takes 3(N-3) comparisons, then the updates take 3(N-1)+Nn+Nw+Ne comparisons, where Nn, Nw, Ne are the number of moves from a vertex to the next; obviously Nn+Nw+Ne = 3N in total).

The modulos are there to implement the cyclic indexing of the edges and vertices.

[image]